# What's a subtle and non-desperate way of saying that I'm looking for a new job on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I have a job, and have neither resigned nor been given notice.

I'd like to let potential new employers on LinkedIn know that I'm looking for a new job, without sounding like I've resigned or been given notice.

I'd also like some plausible deniability with my current employer.

"Open to new opportunities" sounds mildly desperate, and definitely obvious.

Update:

1. This is more for inbound opportunities than outbound.
2. I've received lots of inbound opportunities the last few months, but have replied that I was not looking, so would like to signal that I am indeed now looking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're on LinkedIn, so recruiters can find you. Many will approach you whether you're actively looking or not. They'll try and persuade you regardless.

If you want to attract more attention, update your profile. Post some new things you're doing. Connect to more people. Join some groups.

You could reply to former requests by recruiters to see if they have anything new.

Answer (score 5):

Just apply to jobs through LinkedIn. Don't update your status to say you're looking for a new job. I get solicited for jobs all the time and I have no such status. Most recruiters know people are always looking for better opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

If your company actually notices status switches like that, then it would raise a flag.  I wouldn't change the status on linked in (recruiters don't seem to care one way or the other).  Instead, just start your job search normally.

When you land the new job, switch the status and keep your resume open on the job sites.  That way if you decide to jump again there is no change to notice.

Answer (score 1):

Make your profile public and visible on the usual outlets (Monster etc) and shake your profile on LinkedIn. That causes triggers all over the place and recruiters get notice and start contacting you. You never look for a job, rather a job looks for you. You don't necessarily need to be explicit about, they'll know.